# “The election finished the democratic party as a force in national politics.”

Tags: history, parts-of-speech, emphasis

It doesn’t matter the results of the election or the specific election, I just need to know if this means the party had no influence after the election or if they finished as a force, ie. gained power again? Is this sentence open for interpretation? Thank you so much.

Comment: It only means the former - the party was ruined thereafter.

Comment: @PhilSweet I agree, the opposite would be expressed as "The Democratic Party finished the election as a force in national politics. In the quoted sentence 'The election' is the subject and "The democratic party' is the object.

Comment: @BoldBen I understand now, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The comments deserve to comprise an answer, which is that the statement means the first of your alternatives.

I suggest that the statement also implies that the Democratic Party continued to exist, even though it no longer had any national force.

Note that the construction has its ambiguous dangers, caused by the verb *to finish*,  as exemplified by “Her education finished her as a compelling public speaker”. This statement says that after her education she became a compelling speaker, not that she ceased to be so.